# Kali linux works perfectly in live mode but refuses to load after installation

Tags: kali-linux, system-installation, reboot

I tried using kali Linux on my Asus rog Advantage edition, it works perfectly without any issues in the live version, but after installation it sends my laptop into a series of reboots and black screens until I have switch it off. I suspect the issue is the network card isn't supported after installation, but the network card works perfectly in the live boot mode.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! May I ask why you want to use Kali? Kali is not a regular operating system and should not be used as one. It is a tool designed for experts, and if  you don't know how to debug this sort of issue, that is a good indication that you might want to be using a different Linux flavor instead. Everything you can do in Kali, you can also do with other Linuxes, you just need to install the relevant software. So if you want to learn about security or Linux, please start with something else. https://www.kali.org/docs/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux/

Comment: Kali is not meant to be installed ... as you can see, it works perfectly when used as intended

Comment: Ive completed my network+ and I'm currently preparing for pwk oscp so I wanted to install it on my new laptop but it was a task and a half, I finally figured it out, I've installed kali quite a few times the issue was my new laptop has a weird network card that wasnt supported by the 5.14 kernel, so I disabled it, booted into kali upgraded the kernel to 5.15 and everythings working perfectly!

Comment: I've moved your answer out of the question and into an answer. If you want to post your own version as your own answer I'll happily delete the one I've added

Answer (score 0):

<sup>Moved from question to answer</sup>

I figured out the issue the wireless network card is the MT7921 which didn't have any drivers in the kernel version of my iso. I disabled the nic booted up kali, updated the kernel with an ether connection and after reboot Kali started working perfectly.